# video playback jerks with totem but runs smoothly with parole

Tags: nvidia, video

I recently installed a more powerful graphics card (NVIDIA 4070) which I run on linux (debian bookwork/sid) with the proprietary nvidia drivers.

With my previous card (a less powerful AMD r9 270x), playing FullHD videos was no problem.

With the new card, video playback is smooth when I use the parole video player, but it's jerky when I use the totem video player.

Any ideas?